# compile option for rcpp and lib files in windows

Tags: windows, dll, rcpp

Hi I am trying to work with the rcpp. For this I want some cpp code which loads a dll by use of a lib-file (which has the same name as ). the code which I let run is:

```
cppFunction(includes=c("#include "windef.h","#include \"C:/data/Rdata/IHUAPI.H\" "), 'int functietom(int a){long serverhandle;int lRet;lRet = ihuConnect ( "historian1",NULL,NULL, &serverhandle ); return 5;}', verbose  
 = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

> undefined reference to `ihuConnect@16' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
>   unable to load shared object
>   'C:/Users/user1663/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSW1Ki7/sourcecpp_1a04df63309/sourceCpp_26588.dll':
>   LoadLibrary failure:

the `ihuConnect` function is located in the `ihuapi.lib` and `ihuape.dll`  files. In c++ in visual studio I add the lib file as added dependency and then I get rid of this error because I also sometimes get this error and then it was that I forgot to add the lib file in the compilation.

Thus My question is: how can I add this lib file as option in the compilation.

when I use dyn.load

> ("C:/data/Rdata/ihUAPI.dll")

and then check if it is loaded then he says yes
the problem is that getDLLRegisteredRoutines('ihUAPI', addNames = TRUE)
then it says:
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

so the dll seems not to contain the functions but it does when I use it from visual studio.

So please some help with lib-files and ddl-files

Tom Wambecq

Answer (score 1):

You missed the [Rcpp FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) entry 2.9 'Can I use Rcpp with Visual Studio ?'.

And to kill all the suspense: No, you cannot.